# Не понимаю где нужна библиотека Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

Пикассо нужна чтобы качать картинки из инета. Но в примерах я вижу только сайт imgur. Где ее используют? И примерно как?) Поделитесь кусками кода пожалуйста :)

Comment: А чем кроме базового примера из доки с любым другим url мы можем вам помочь-то?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Picasso есть несколько "фич", за которые ее любят:

1. она умеет показывать картинки, расположенные где угодно: в сети, в assets, где-то в хранилище, в ресурсах
2. она операции по преобразованию картинок проводит в worker thread в порядке очереди. то есть ее можно применить при отображении картинок в длинном списке в ListView/RecyclerView, и пользователь, быстро проматывая список, не займет процессор преобразованием картинок на минуту вперед
3. она справляется с большими картинками, не порождая OutOfMemoryException

Ну и дальше по мелочи, включая плейсхолдеры и кеширование.

Как ее использовать, написано [на ее странице](http://square.github.io/picasso/). В том и прелесть, что единообразные 5 строчек на все случаи жизни.

Comment: Спасибо но я бы хотел узнать другое. Например на сервере интернет магазина лежат картинки товаров. Как их качать? По url? А как же на сервере тогда все делается? Картинка должна быть на отдельной странице?

Comment: Да, это вопрос не про Picasso. Вам стоит сначала почитать про протокол HTTP - для чего он предназначен и что он может. Тогда проще будет понять, как взаимодействовать с сервером, и как он должен и может быть устроен. Пока подсказка: сервер - это не компьютер в специальной комнате, сервер - это программа. Почитаете про HTTP - задайте новый вопрос еще раз.